# different view on android and desktop

Tags: android, css, desktop

i have problem with different appearance between android and desktop.
not about responsive, but a simple css appearance

i have this

```
<div class="related">
   <h3>Related Posts</h3>
</div>
```

with css:

```
.related {
    height: 30px;
}
.related h3 {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

on desktop, h3 lined perfectly in the middle of .related bar, while on android (galaxy grand prime) h3 lined a little bit above, closer to top, around 40% closer to top than 60% to bottom. so 20% difference, which is very visible.

am i missing something? is this Android bug? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The @media rule is used to define different style rules for different media types/devices. Media types look at the capability of the device, and can be used to check many things, such as:  width and apply different css to that device.
Example : `@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {}`
Different devices often behave totally differently and different browsers differently again.

Comment: yeah, i'm already using @media rule for the responsive design. but i'm speechless how come simple and old css property (line-height and height) behave so different. i'm guessing this is because pixel ratio. what the best solution i have? i don't know if purposedly made the h3 a little bit low for smaller screen is good solution, will it behave the same on different android devices?

Comment: Not always because different devices have pixel ratio.